# Thread runs After activity life cycle?

Tags: android, multithreading, activity-lifecycle

I have network operation inside a thread which in `oncreate()` based on network response I need to process the next step but the thread is running after the activity life cycle.

I called networkRequest() in oncreate() in activity

```
private void networkRequest() {

 final String[] resp = new String[1];
 Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
   try {
    resp[0] = AttemptingUploadCheckList.getJsonObj(url);
    JSONObject response = new JSONObject(resp[0]);

    if (response != null) {
     version_code = response.getInt("version_code");
     recommended_update = response.getBoolean("recommended_update");
     forced_update = response.getBoolean("forced_update");
    }
    if (recommended_update) {
     recomendUpadate();
    } else if (forced_update)
     onUpdateNeeded(url);
    else {
     Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
     startActivity(intent);
     finish();
    }

   } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
  }
 });
 thread.start();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> `Thread` is not bound with the activity. It's not running with the main thread.

`Android` said if you want to perform any long running tasks like `api call`, `data from database` then you need to use the [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask) or the [Service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services).

In your case, you can use the `AsycnTask` for the fetching data.

```
class MyAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{
        final String[] resp = new String[1];
        JSONObject response;
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            // Show Progress Dialog
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);

            // Hide Progress Dialog

            if (response != null) {
                version_code = response.getInt("version_code");
                recommended_update = response.getBoolean("recommended_update");
                forced_update = response.getBoolean("forced_update");
            }
            if (recommended_update) {
                recomendUpadate();
            } else if (forced_update)
                onUpdateNeeded(url);
            else {
                Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {

                        try {
                            resp[0] = AttemptingUploadCheckList.getJsonObj(url);
                            response = new JSONObject(resp[0]);

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

            return null;
        }
    }
```

For executing the above `AsynTask`

```
private void networkRequest() {
       new MyAsync().execute();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> `Thread` does not care about `Activity` or any other Component's lifecycle Except the Process in which it is Running.

You need to check for state of component yourself.
I can provide some example code but i really do not understand what exactly you are trying to do .

Considering you are making a network request there. Java thread individually is hard to handle in such cases considering the fact that after response we need to move on to Main thread to update the UI. So i highly recommend you should use a Network API Library probably [RetroFit](https://square.github.io/retrofit/) .
You can check state of the Component like  `isFinishing()` in `Activity` .